# Wrong encoding even when specifying encoding to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a CSV file that contains accentuated characters. I checked the encoding while opening with PyCharm and Sublime, it's Western: Windows 1252, or ISO-8859-1.

I create a pandas dataframe from this CSV, then modify it, and export it to an UTF-8 text file. I check the exported file with PyCharm and Sublime Text, I don't know why the exported file is not in UTF-8.

Here is my code:

```py
dataset= pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", sep=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
print(dataset.loc[0, "my_col"])
>>> "s'il vous plaît"

# Export data
with open("out.txt"), "w", newline='') as f:
    dataset.to_csv(path_or_buf=f, sep="\t", header=False, index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

When opening "out.txt" with PyCharm, it shows `s'il vous pla�t`, and PyCharm tells me that the encoding of the file is not UTF-8.

Comment: give us a copy of your csv file. thanks.

Comment: Well if you want. It contains "s'il vous plaît".

Comment: i'm getting this error: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'

Comment: syntax error on with open()...

Comment: Could you please [edit] to show a hex dump of the problematic string? See also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info)

Comment: I'm guessing your code is fine and you just somehow examine it in a place where UTF-8 support is broken or missing.

Comment: Are you trying to get this bytestring: b"s'il vous pla\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbf\xc2\xbdt"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're writing through a file object in text mode with **default encoding**, this takes output encoding precedence over and makes `encoding` parameter in the method `to_csv` useless.

You should use something like the following instead.

```py
# Export data
with open("out.txt", "w", newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    dataset.to_csv(path_or_buf=f, sep="\t", header=False, index=False)
```

Or without a file object:

```py
# Export data
dataset.to_csv(path_or_buf="out.txt", sep="\t", header=False, index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```